# Rails with mmenu/sidr with Jquery and Turbolinks issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, mmenu, sidr

I haven't been able to get to the bottom of this but there was suspicion  that turbolinks was the culprit. Changing menus just to make sure it wasn't some odd mmenu issue.

I open the page, click the menu button - it works, it opens the side menu, I click a link within the menu, and it goes back to my app. The menu button then doesn't fire anymore. Originally when I had with mmenu, it seemed to be missing the click event associated with mmenu. With sidr, it seems to be there, but nothing happens.

I've set up my jquery like this

[Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Example sidr

```
<a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr">Menu link</a>

<div id="sidr">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS file included in tree

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

    $('#simple-menu').sidr();

};

$(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

I've already set up my application.js with jquery turbolinks gem e.g.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery-ui/core
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require jquery.mmenu.min
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean `$('#sidr').sidr();`?

Comment: had a link that didn't encase in code. no it should be simple-menu apparently http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#

Comment: the only complete fix i have been able to find is to disable turbolinks completely... would love to get it reintegrated and have both working

Comment: i'm having the exact same problem. upon initial page load, the menu works as expected. but clicking a link from within the menu somehow breaks the menu on the next page. what's weird is that other turbolinks requests work fine. i can click on a link outside the menu, and the menu will open up on the next page. very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Mmenu and Turbolinks. And I've done as evanbikes describes. Disabling turbolinks and Mmenu works. But when enabling it it just doesn't work after clicking a link in the menu.
Everything else works, all our js-code. So this must be something that has to do with Turbolinks.

https://github.com/karlingen/rails4_mmenu

https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/41

Would love to use Mmenu, but it's impossible at the moment with Turbolinks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Install 'jquery-turbolinks' https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

then simply

```js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation

    // Make sure to add your code here
    // For example with foundation it is:


$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Hope it helps. At least it worked fine for me.

Comment: hey your answer really helped on a problem i was struggling on. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts:

1) Make sure that you have your javascript includes in the head and not the bottom of the body. Since Turbolinks reloads the body every time, you would be reloading the same javascript and probably reinitializing duplicate listeners.

2) With the jquery.turbolinks gem, you should only need `$(ready)` and not `$(document).on('page:load', ready)`. That is theoretically what jquery.turbolinks does for you.

3) Is `ready` firing at all? Did you put a `console.log` or `alert` in there to see?

4) Are you loading things through ajax or something *after* the DOM is ready? If so, you'll need to call `.sidr()` manually whenever it actually appears on the page, even if it is after DOM ready.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i'm going to look into this again next week!

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration, I finally discovered that someone made a pull request on the GitHub repo for this exact issue. It hasn't been merged as of the time of this answer, but it's a quick fix, and it works like a charm!

https://github.com/artberri/sidr/pull/183/files

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jquery.sidemenu.js which is a mmenu jQuery plugin compatible with Turbolinks.

https://github.com/kami30k/jquery.sidemenu.js/

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to fix this issue. From Turbolinks [Doc - Opting out of Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) you can add `data-no-turbolink` attribute to disable turbolink on that particular div tag. So modify your code as below and it will work without any issue.

```
<div id="sidr">
<!-- Your content -->
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
  <li class="active" data-no-turbolink><a href="/">List 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but want to leave an updated solution fro somebody who might be looking.

Mmenu developers added wrappers to support various frameworks, including turbolinks: [mmenu framework wrappers](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/framework-wrappers.html)

So now, all you need to do to solve this turbolinks bug is to download latest version of mmenu from their site or github repo and include the file located in dist/wrappers/turbolinks after your main mmenu file.

In case you include them manually, it's gonna look like this:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.mmenu.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="path/to/jquery.mmenu.wordpress.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And if you are using sprockets, like this:

```
//= require jquery.mmenu
//= require jquery.mmenu.turbolinks
```